SP2019 Rest API: Syntax to retreive two properties
I am having trouble retrieving both the File name and the File size (FileLeafRef,File/Length) in the same API results. The endpoint below only displays the File Name.
I welcome advice on correcting my syntax to get both properties back in one response.
"[Base URL]+/_api/lists/getbytitle('"+[Library Name]+"')/items?$select=FileLeafRef,File/Length"

You need to add &$expand=File to your request.
https://your-webapp/sites/your-site/_api/lists/getbytitle('Your library')/items?$select=FileLeafRef,File/Length&$expand=File

